# Test angularjs with Jasmine using stand alone command line interface

Tags: angularjs, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a simple .js file and its test on Jasmine. I'm able to run the test successfully through Jasmine's stand alone SpecRunner.html.

Is it possible to do the same on command line interface? I do have node installed along with jasmine,

```
npm install -g jasmine
```

Tests using Jasmine Command line interface works for simple javascript functions that return simple objects. However if I start using angular libraries, it results in:

```
})(window, document);
   ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/spec/helpers/lib/angularjs/1_4_4/angular.js:28602:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/nodejs/node-v6.11.4-darwin-x64/lib/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:99:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

/helpers/jasmine-examples/my-sourcefile.js

```
var myModule = angular.module('myApplication', []);

myModule.controller('SimpleController', function($scope) {
        $scope.amount = ['a','b','c'];
});
```

/helpers/jasmine-examples/my-sourcefile.spec.js

```
describe('a simple controller', function(){
    var $scope;

    //See API angular.mock.module
    beforeEach(module('myApplication'));

    beforeEach( inject( function( $rootScope, $controller ){
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('SimpleController',{$scope : $scope});
    }));

    it('test scope amount', function(){
        expect($scope.amount.length).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

jasmine.json

```
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/jasmine_examples/*.js",
    "helpers/lib/angularjs/1_4_4/angular.js",
    "helpers/lib/angularjs/1_4_4/angular-mocks.js"
  ],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": false
}
```

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: The problem it's that jasmine doesn't have a DOM where run the tests. I've recommend that use [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) that brings with a jsdom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need control it with Karma, if you wanna test angular in server side. [Here](https://github.com/joelbarbosa/restautantDB/blob/master/front-api/karma.conf.js) an example angular and karma. 
Karma will simulate a browser.